# Replacing current theme folder by previous version of the same folder produces "undefined function get_header()" error

Tags: themes

In order to check a previous version of my theme, I temporarily moved my current theme folder elsewhere and put at its location the folder of an older version of the same theme, with the same name.

However I get a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in ...\index.php on line 1" message. Why on earth would this happen?

Comment: Quite likely, one of the files called inside the header is missing.  If you swapped the entire theme folder, css, js and all other assets were also moved in/out temporarily?  Sounds like an asset is being asked for in your current theme that is missing in the older version.

Comment: `get_header()` is a Core function. It should not be undefined because a theme asset is missing.